# JS Hide header elements and resize navigation bar on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a large header section for a website that is split into three sections; social links, logo, and then the navigation bar. I am trying to figure out how I can hide the top two elements and resize the navigation bar and have it fixed when the user scrolls past it.

The nav bar currently just holds a link that will open up a separate side menu that holds all of the actual page navigation.

https://jsfiddle.net/cxekxrxy/2/

```
<header>
    <!-- social links -->
    <div id="social" class="social-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- logo -->
    <div id="logo" class="logo-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="logo-main">Main Header</h1>
                <h2 class="logo-sub">Sub Header</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div id="header" class="main-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="bars"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger text-right" id="nav-bars" style="font-size:25px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <!-- nav links (hidden until <span> is pressed) -->
        <div id="main-nav" class="side-nav"> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnClose" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="default.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> About</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"> Portfolio</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> Contact</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this neat example for your need: 
https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/
And work with your code.

This is combination CSS and JS, and a simplest solution
.